# C Time.h functions erratic on Precise 12.04

Tags: 12.04, c++, time

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and using the gcc compiler to compile my C/C++ programs. I want to benchmark a function. AFAIK, there are two standard functions to calculate time on POSIX systems and both are showing erratic results on Ubuntu:

gettimeofday
clock_gettime

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    float msec=0;
    //struct timespec start,end;
    struct timeval start,end;

    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&start);
    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);

        get_height(); //function i want to benchmark

/*  usleep(1000000);*/

    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);

    //msec = (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000 + (end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)/(float)1000000;
    msec = (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000 + (end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/(float)1000;
    printf("%0.2f ms.\n",msec); //41-44

}
```

The trouble is that the millisecond being displayed are showing erratic/different results each time the program is run. Some sample readings are:
38.16 ms.
42.72 ms.
35.70 ms.
45.13 ms.

However, when I test with the usleep() function, the result shows 1000 ms. properly. Any idea what library/function should I use to time my functions accurately ?

**EDIT:**
This is to further clarify that the said clock_gettime functions are only inaccurate on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tested on other machines where it showed accurate results. Even on windows, the equivalent query_performance_counter() functions showed accurate results.

Comment: Unless this behavior only happens in Ubuntu this question seems better suited to Stack Overflow. Either way the only tool I have used in this field is `gprof`([tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/)): see if it helps.

Comment: On-topic or not? [How should we interpret “Development on Ubuntu” in the FAQ?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5744/88802) OP: could you elaborate a bit more on what you've tried on other OSs? It seems that you've tried others reading between the lines.

Comment: @gertvdijk - On windows OS, I've tried QueryPerformanceCounter which works accurately showing the same results each time within 1 milliseconds accuraccy. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: I'm looking a similar substitute for POSIX systems and Ubuntu is the only unix-like system I've got to test.

Comment: @Salem - The gprof alternative looks good, but I'm aiming for less dependencies and something that works from inside the code with least dependencies.

Comment: Works on Windows, doesn't work on Ubuntu. Looks on-topic to me. OP: could you **edit** your question instead of posting new information in comments? That is how this site works.

Comment: @gertvdijk - Just did the same.

Comment: This is perfectly normal. Your computer is doing more than just your "benchmark", so timings vary. Run your benchmark many times, and use statistics. See also http://blogs.perl.org/users/steffen_mueller/2010/09/your-benchmarks-suck.html

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker - Thanks for the info. In that case which function do you suggest I use for time tracking in C/C++? gettimeofday() or clock_gettime() ?